# How to measure touch pressure in Android in all activity?

Tags: android

I know that it is easy to measure the touch pressure by using the function getPressure() provided by android API within an application activity.

However, I would like to measure all the motionevents (not only within the application activiy, but also outside the application activity).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think this is not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, thankfully.

For security reasons, Android does not allow you to intercept touch events on anything outside of your own App's Activities. If this were allowed, a malicious app could take over and render the device useless by simply consuming all the touch events.